# Error: Compile Error: Unexpected token '='. at line 4 column 9

Tags: apex

[image]Please help me to find what is the error in this snippet.

> Error: Compile Error: Unexpected token '='. at line 4 column 9

```
Public Class Test{

   List<Opportunity> opp = New List<Opportunity>();
    opp = [select id from Opportunity];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part, code needs to be put inside of a *method* which is itself inside of a class.

```java
public class MyClass {
    // Declaring and initializing a static or member/instance variable is fine
    List<Account> myAccountList = new List<Account>();

    // Updating or overwriting variables cannot be done outside of a method
    // The below is invalid and thus commented out
    //myAccountList = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 10];

    public void myMethod() {
        // Most code needs to be inside of a method
        myAccountList = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 10];
    }
}
```

If you aren't already using https://trailhead.salesforce.com, you probably should be. The [Developer Beginner trail](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/force_com_dev_beginner) (and specifically the Apex Basics & Database module within it) is going to be a better resource to help get you started. It does assume that you have some knowledge of Object-Oriented Programming (OOP).

Comment: Note: static initialization blocks (and even _instance_ initialization blocks) are a thing. They can also contain code, but I've left that detail out as OP isn't yet at a stage where they should be worrying about that.

Comment: Thank you. I have started learning it.